# Camera motion animation does not work in VR mode

Tags: aframe

Camera motion animation does not work in VR mode on Android in Google chrome. Code example:

```
<a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA">
  <a-assets>
    <img id="room1" src="img/pano_1.jpg">
  </a-assets>     
  <a-entity id="cam" camera position="0 1.6 0" look-controls animation__zoomin="property:position;dur:5000;delay:5000;to:0 1.6 -300" animation__zoomout="property:position;dur:10;delay:10000;to:0 1.6 0"></a-entity>
  <a-sky id="skybox" src="#room1"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animate a [camera rig](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/camera.html#examples) instead of
the camera.